# Can I stage or unstage some files in parallel?

Tags: libgit2, libgit2sharp

I want to stage/unstage some large binary files, it take a long time to call Commands.Stage and Commands.Unstage. So I'm wondering can I call them using Parallel.ForeachAsync. Do you know?